# How to moving top line to the bottom of the text in css

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with css or html, which to move the line as show below the picture from first circle to the second circle. I have posted my version of JSfiddle as show below:

[image]

JSFiddle code:

https://jsfiddle.net/odzuwsdt/

HTML:

```
<section  id="intro" class="workhide">
  <div class="content_section with_border">
    <div  class="content"><span  class="label">Werk</span>
      <h1>
        Zo trots als een hond met zeven staarten. <br > Ben ik op mijn werk. Denk jij nu: 'Dat wil ik ook!'?<br > mail mij!
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.content_section.with_border:before {
    content: "";
    width: 10%;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    left: 0;
    top: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #1d1b22;
    clear: both;
}

.content_section.with_border .label {
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
}

h1, h2 {
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 1.60714em;
    line-height: 1.24444em;
    margin: 0 0 .64286em;
}

.content_section.with_border .content {
    padding: 0 11%;
    clear: both;
}

.content_section .label {
    font-size: .5em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 800;
}
```

Anybody knows how to solve it?

Comment: What is the wrong with my answer why down voted?

Comment: For better design , we should avoid use of position style. And i have avoided it and did as you wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working snippet with comments:

```css
/* Added */
.content_section.with_border {
  position: relative;
}

.content_section.with_border:before {
  content: "";
  width: 10%;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -4px; /* modified top -> bottom, value can be modified to adjust position */
  position: absolute;
  background: #1d1b22;
  clear: both;
}

.content_section.with_border .label {
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 1.60714em;
  line-height: 1.24444em;
  margin: 0 0 .64286em;
}

.content_section.with_border .content {
  padding: 0 11%;
  clear: both;
}

.content_section .label {
  font-size: .5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 800;
}
```

```html
<section id="intro" class="workhide">
  <div class="content_section with_border">
    <div class="content"><span class="label">Werk</span>
      <h1>
        Zo trots als een hond met zeven staarten. <br> Ben ik op mijn werk. Denk jij nu: 'Dat wil ik ook!'?<br> mail mij!
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: That's Literally what the other answer is.

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa Well, we were surely answering at the same time. I have the working snippet as a plus. ;)

Comment: @Takit Isy your answer is correct, I want it to be under the text. For the first answer, if i stretch the line, it will overlap the text which is quite a ugly thing. The reason why I wanted to be under it as I wanted to animated including the line when user first loaded the page.

Answer (score 2):

add `position:relative` for parent div and add `bottom` instead of `top`

```
.content_section.with_border{
  position: relative;
}
.content_section.with_border:before {
  content: "";
  width: 10%;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #1d1b22;
}
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/odzuwsdt/2/

Answer (score -2):

Try changing your css code to something like this.

```
.content_section {
  position: relative;
}

.content_section.with_border:before {
  content: "";
  width: 10%;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: #1d1b22;
}

.content_section.with_border .label {
  position: relative;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 1.60714em;
  line-height: 1.24444em;
  margin: 0 0 .64286em;
}

.content_section.with_border .content {
  padding: 0 11%;
}

.content_section .label {
  font-size: .5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 800;
}
```

Comment: let's don't repeat the same answer again and again ... it's already provided twice